Facing the error again and again in swift ui and can't able to find the solution
This are the errors are  occurs but this issue shows me after a few days before I was able too make the app but now this error message are coming in very file I have e24 issue in this error I have try many way to resolve this issue but any of them didn't work I have tried to uninstall the Xcode nd install it the clean the build but still facing these issues
error 1

The compiler is unable to type-check this expression in reasonable time; try breaking up the expression into distinct sub-expressions.

error 2

Missing argument for parameter 'from' in call ,Static method 'buildExpression' requires that 'Button' conform to 'View' , Cannot infer contextual base in reference to member 'horizontal'Cannot infer contextual base in reference to member 'top' ,Value of type 'Button' has no member 'navigationDestination'


struct TrackSlotDropDown: View {
    let title: String
    let prompt: String
    let options: [String]
    
    @Binding var selection: String?
    @State private var isExpanded = false
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 10) {
            Text(title)
                .font(.footnote)
                .foregroundColor(.black)
                .opacity(0.8)
                .padding(.horizontal)
            
            HStack {
                Text(selection ?? prompt)
                Spacer()
                Image(systemName: "chevron.down")
                    .font(.subheadline)
                    .foregroundColor(.gray)
                    .rotationEffect(.degrees(isExpanded ? 180 : 0))
            }
            .frame(height: 30)
            .padding(.horizontal)
            .onTapGesture {
                isExpanded.toggle() // Toggle dropdown state
            }
            .background(Color.white)
            .overlay(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 2).stroke(Color.black))
            .padding(.horizontal)
        }
        .overlay(
            GeometryReader { geometry in
                if isExpanded {
                    VStack {
                        Spacer()
                        VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 0) {
                            ForEach(options, id: \.self) { option in
                                Button(action: {
                                    selection = option
                                    isExpanded.toggle() // Close dropdown when an option is selected
                                }) {
                                    HStack {
                                        Text(option)
                                            .foregroundColor(selection == option ? Color.primary : Color.gray)
                                        Spacer()
                                        
                                        if selection == option {
                                            Image(systemName: "checkmark")
                                                .font(.subheadline)
                                        }
                                    }
                                    
                                    .frame(height: 40) // Adjust height as needed
                                    .padding(.horizontal)
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        .background(Color.white) // Background for dropdown options
                        .cornerRadius(8) // Rounded corners for dropdown options
                        .padding(10) // Add padding for dropdown options
                        .shadow(radius: 5) // Add shadow for depth
                        .frame(width: geometry.size.width * 0.8) // Set width to 80% of screen width
                        .alignmentGuide(.top) { _ in geometry.size.height * 0.5 } // Center vertically
                        Spacer()
                    }
                    .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all) // Ignore safe area to cover entire screen
                    .onTapGesture {
                        isExpanded.toggle() // Close dropdown when tapping outside
                    }
                }
            }
        )
        .padding(.top, 5)
    }
}

#Preview {
    TrackSlotDropDown(title: "Status", prompt: "Select", options: ["pending", "approved", "Inspection completed", "Pending uploaded"], selection: .constant("pending"))
}

that error coming in every file I want a solution for this

Show a minimal reproducible code that produces your issue, see: minimal code .
Your code (with some assumptions) works well for me.
The errors probably do not come from the code you show.

Sometimes it can help to do as the compiler suggests and break up the view into sub-views.
When I tried that with the code you posted, it compiles and even runs fine:
struct TrackSlotDropDown: View {
    let title: String
    let prompt: String
    let options: [String]

    @Binding var selection: String?
    @State private var isExpanded = false

    private var baseContent: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 10) {
            Text(title)
                .font(.footnote)
                .foregroundColor(.black)
                .opacity(0.8)
                .padding(.horizontal)

            HStack {
                Text(selection ?? prompt)
                Spacer()
                Image(systemName: "chevron.down")
                    .font(.subheadline)
                    .foregroundColor(.gray)
                    .rotationEffect(.degrees(isExpanded ? 180 : 0))
            }
            .frame(height: 30)
            .padding(.horizontal)
            .onTapGesture {
                isExpanded.toggle() // Toggle dropdown state
            }
            .background(Color.white)
            .overlay(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 2).stroke(Color.black))
            .padding(.horizontal)
        }
    }

    private var overlayContent: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            if isExpanded {
                VStack {
                    Spacer()
                    VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 0) {
                        ForEach(options, id: \.self) { option in
                            Button(action: {
                                selection = option
                                isExpanded.toggle() // Close dropdown when an option is selected
                            }) {
                                HStack {
                                    Text(option)
                                        .foregroundColor(selection == option ? Color.primary : Color.gray)
                                    Spacer()

                                    if selection == option {
                                        Image(systemName: "checkmark")
                                            .font(.subheadline)
                                    }
                                }

                                .frame(height: 40) // Adjust height as needed
                                .padding(.horizontal)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    .background(Color.white) // Background for dropdown options
                    .cornerRadius(8) // Rounded corners for dropdown options
                    .padding(10) // Add padding for dropdown options
                    .shadow(radius: 5) // Add shadow for depth
                    .frame(width: geometry.size.width * 0.8) // Set width to 80% of screen width
                    .alignmentGuide(.top) { _ in geometry.size.height * 0.5 } // Center vertically
                    Spacer()
                }
                .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all) // Ignore safe area to cover entire screen
                .onTapGesture {
                    isExpanded.toggle() // Close dropdown when tapping outside
                }
            }
        }
    }

    var body: some View {
        baseContent
            .overlay(overlayContent)
            .padding(.top, 5)
    }
}


@KrishChhabra Not very keen on participating in a meeting, sorry. Try following the suggestions being made to you (provide an example that actually fails to compile, split up the code into smaller fragments).

I have split the code into smaller fragments and  its does not showing any error but  when I give the build its showing the same issue with some extra errors Extra arguments at positions #1, #2 in call,Missing argument for parameter 'from' in call,Insert 'from: <#any Decoder#>, ', Cannot infer contextual base in reference to member 'horizontal', Value of type 'Button' has no member 'padding'.            Button(action:{
dismiss()
}) {
Image("arrow-left")
}
.padding(.horizontal,16)

@KrishChhabra A small error somewhere, such as an extra parenthesis or curly brace, can often lead to a flood of obscure errors, many of which can have misleading descriptions. You are just going to have to debug your code and find the error that is triggering it all off. Try looking for misspelt parameters, misspelt property names, wrong parentheses or wrong curly braces. Breaking up the code and/or commenting out large sections can be a good way to narrow it down. Good luck!
